# Can Product_ID of products in Opencart be alphanumeric?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, ebay-api

I am working on a project where I am trying to check some validations but I find a risk of 'product_id' parameter is not properly sanitized upon submission to the `index.php` script, which can disclose the software's installation path resulting in a loss of confidentiality.

so after checking the format of product_id of products, its only in numeric but is there any possibility that the format may be alphanumeric and if yes then what exactly will be the behavior.

Comment: i think you want want to display your product id or path ? if yes then just use  SEF urls for your products, category etc .

Answer (score 0):

Don't change it's data type because it's relation exists in 5-6 tables, SO better create a new field for it's alphanumeric Id and control it using php..

Answer (score 0):

The product id is the foriegn key for 5-6 tables eg) product option contains the product id as referance so please dont